# Curl xml Response in Php

Tags: php, curl

i need to post Data in Xml to a server but whnen i use a basic curl post i have a redirect page to the curl url , but when i use something like postman it works just find , I even tried the code generated by postman and i got the same results (redirect) 
here is my curl

```
 $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "URL");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ["SAMLResponse"=> $xml]);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    $headers[] = "authorization: Basic CODE";

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $output = (curl_exec($ch));
```

Comment: remove "[ ]" and directly set  "SAMLResponse=" . $xml, i think i should work

Comment: Thank you for your answer , itried it and i get the redirect page again , 
another thing , is that if i tried to post data local so i can see the output i get the redirect again to my project login page ; is that normal

Comment: postman automatically follow redirects. make curl follow suite. curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);

Comment: thank you but i think the problem is from the cookie exchange , i need to get a hold of it and i don't know how